# Streaming opencv to youtube with ffmpeg

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, youtube, video-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to live stream to youtube from a c++ opencv project. Currently, my program outputs a RTMP stream which nginx should push to youtube. A problem I'm having is youtube's requirement for an audio stream.

I'm trying a workaround by restreaming using ffmpeg. It adds an empty audio stream (not efficient). Another issue is the output speed of my program which is around 10 fps. When playing in vlc or youtube, the stream buffers for a while and plays a few seconds of smooth video. How should I set this up in c++ to play a constant stream with lower fps, including an empty audio stream?
Example I used: https://github.com/andreanobile/opencv_ffmpeg_streaming

FFMPEG for adding audio:
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -hwaccel cuvid -i rtmp://localhost/live -vf scale=3840:2160 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset fast -maxrate 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -b:a 160k -ac 2 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/